# how to make a variable global inside a while loop

Tags: while-loop, tcl

Following is the TCL script to print numbers between 1 to 10 using while loop.

```
set b 1

while {$b<11} {
    puts $b
    incr b
}
```

In the above script, how to make "puts $b" output as global. So that we can use this where ever we want in the script?

I need the following:

```
set b 1

while {$b<11} {
    set a $b
    incr b
}

puts "This is number $a"
```

If I use `$a` in outside loop, it should print the output as :

```
This is number 1
This is number 2
This is number 3
.
.
.
This is number 10
```

Comment: I can't quite make sense of your question. You are printing `This is number $a` only once but you want it to appear more than once? Why not put `puts ...` into the while loop? Or alternatively, use a `proc` in the loop that `puts` the value of `$a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl is really strictly operational; it does things at the point where you tell it to. However, one of the things that you can do is to put a [`trace`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm) on a variable so that some code gets run whenever the variable is written to.

```
# This is Tcl 8.5 syntax; let me know if you want it for 8.4 and before
trace add variable ::a write {apply {args {
   puts "This is number $::a"
}}}
```

<sup>I've used fully-qualified variable names above; the trace is really on the variable `a` in the namespace `::`.</sup>
Then, *after setting the trace*, when we do:

```
set b 1

while {$b<11} {
    set a $b
    incr b
}
```

The output then is:

```
This is number 1
This is number 2
This is number 3
This is number 4
This is number 5
This is number 6
This is number 7
This is number 8
This is number 9
This is number 10
```

Which is what you wanted.

Comment: Hi Donal Fellows, Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to make use of $a outside a loop. My requirement is to make this $a as global (like procedure). For example write a proc for while loop, using that proc name I should get the "This is number 1 ..." output. Please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear: I think Donal Fellows may have given you the right answer, but I think I may see another question lurking in your text, namely: how can I write a generic command that will, as it were, take a variable for a brief spin?

As in:

```
set b 1

myLoop b {
    set a $b
    puts "This is number $a"
}
puts "Again, this is number $a"
```

You would write `myLoop` like this:

```
proc myLoop {varName body} {
    upvar 1 $varName i
    for {} {$i < 11} {incr i} {
        uplevel 1 $body
    }
}
```

Note that this is not the best way to write a command like this: I'm writing it this way to accommodate your example code.

The command works by calling `uplevel` to evaluate the script in `body` in the context of the caller, whichever that is. To allow `myLoop` to manipulate the variable in the script, we need to set up things so that the command will share the variable with the caller. The `upvar` command does that.

Comment: "Not the best way" - so what is?